# Spark Count number of lines with a particular word in it

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a log file which has lines containing the word "error" in it. How do i count the total number of lines containing this term in apache spark?

So far i am using this approach.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("WordCount")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

input = sc.textFile("errors.txt")
words = input.flatMap(lambda x: x for x if "errors" in input)
wordCounts = input.countByValue()

for word, count in wordCounts.items():
    print str(count)
```

But this method doesnt work. Can anyone tell me how do i get the count?

Edit: Equivalent in scala is

```
lines = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
errors = lines.filter(_.startsWith("ERROR"))
errors.persist()
```

what is the python equivalent of this line.

Comment: `rdd.count` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the below snippet:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("errors")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("errors.txt")
rdd = lines.filter(lambda x: "error" in x)
print rdd.count
```

Answer (score 1):

`input.filter(lambda line : "error" in line).count()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. I was able to solve it in another way

```
input = sc.textFile("errors.txt")
wordCounts = input.countByValue()

for word, count in wordCounts.items():
    if "error" in word:
        print count
```